# OptimisticConcurrencyException thrown when inserting record with UDT primary key

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, exception

I have a database table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Configurations]
(
    [ConfigurationId] dbo.InternalRecordId NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 1, 
    [EnableAuditLogging] BIT NOT NULL
)
```

Note that the primary key's type is a user-defined type (UDT):

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[InternalRecordId]
    FROM int NOT NULL
```

Records from this table are mapped into a normal data-type object:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool EnableAuditLogging { get; set; }
}
```

I've configured Entity Framework to map the `Id` property to the `ConfigurationId` column as a non-identity primary key. I've used the debugger to verify that this mapping code is actually run.

```
class ConfigurationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entities.Configuration>
{
    public ConfigurationMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);
        Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasColumnName("ConfigurationId")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(null);
    }
}
```

When I use Entity Framework to insert a record into the table as shown below:

```
var database = new LocalDbContext();
var configuration = new Configuration
{
    Id = 1,
};
database.Configurations.Add(configuration);
database.SaveChanges();
```

Then the call to `SaveChanges` throws an `OptimisticConcurrencyException`, advising that the record wasn't found it the table after insertion.

I used SQL Server Profiler to check what it was doing:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Configurations]([EnableAuditLogging])
VALUES (@0)
SELECT [ConfigurationId]
FROM [dbo].[Configurations]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ConfigurationId] = scope_identity()
```

I noticed that it's not specifying the value for `ConfigurationId` in the `INSERT` statement, and it's also trying to get the value from `scope_identity` even though it's not an `IDENTITY` column.

When I change the column's type to `int` instead of the UDT, the problem no longer occurs.

Comment: I've created a work item for this [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1866). I recommend you vote for it if you also want this functionaliy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to this line:

```
HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(null);
```

The documentation for this method states:

> Setting 'null' will remove the database generated pattern facet from the property. Setting 'null' will cause the same runtime behavior as specifying 'None'.

Despite the second sentence, I tried changing this to:

```
HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

This fixed the problem. So it looks like setting it to `null` does **not** do the same thing as specifying `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`.